# Necessary and Sufficient Condition for Observer Convergence

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the linear dynamical system
$$\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$$
$$y(t)=Cx(t)+d(t),$$
for all $t\geq 0$. The common observer design to estimate the state $x$ while observing the output $y$ is given by the Luenberger observer:
$$\dot{\hat{x}}(t)=A\hat{x}(t)+L(y(t)-C\hat{x}(t)).$$
Indeed, if $A-LC$ is Hurwitz (all eigenvalues have negative real part) and the disturbance $d=0$ then the estimation error
$$e(t):=x(t)-\hat{x}(t)\longrightarrow 0,$$
as $t$ goes to infinity.

On the other hand, denote the non-negative real line by $\mathcal{R}^+$. We say a function $\gamma:\mathcal{R}^+\longrightarrow\mathcal{R}^+$ is of class $K$ if $\gamma(0)=0$, it is strictly increasing and continuous. A function $\beta:\mathcal{R}^+\times\mathcal{R}^+\longrightarrow\mathcal{R}^+$ is of class $\mathcal{KL}$ if $\beta(\cdot,r)$ is of class $\mathcal{K}$ and $\beta(s,\cdot)$ is decreasing such that for each $s$:
$$\beta(s,t)\longrightarrow 0,$$
as $t$ goes to infinity.

The Luenberger observer has the property that there exist such functions satisfying:
$$|e(t)|\leq\beta(|e(0)|,t)+\gamma(|d|_\infty),$$
for all $t\geq 0$ where the disturbance $d$ is bounded with supremum norm $|d|_\infty$.

For general non-linear systems with specific structures, the bounded/convergent observers respectively corresponding to noisy/perfect outputs that I know satisfy this property also. Is it equivalent to the boundedness/convergence of the observer or is it a much stronger assumption?